# JS: вынести классы програмы в отдельные файлы

Tags: javascript, файлы

Добрый день, ситуация такова: учу JS, и сейчас делаю простую консольную игрушку как упражнение, проблема в том, что я хочу использовать ООП, и каждый класс программы вынести в отдельный файл. Каким образом я могу соединить файлы, чтобы они "знали" друг о друге.

P.S. когда я учил  java и писал код через intellij idea, файлы с классами автоматически соединялись между собой и эта проблема никогда не возникала, сейчас использую Atom, и хотелось бы узнать принцип по которому это работает.

Файл 1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/World.js"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Vector.js"> </script>
```

файл 2  Vector.js

```
class Vector { constructor(x,y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; } }
```

файл 3  World.js

```
//в соседнем файле: 
var x = new Vector(1,5);
//Uncaught ReferenceError:     turn is not defined at World.js:30
```

Comment: "Каким образом я могу соединить файлы" - включить их в одну страницу.

Comment: Окей, но допустим у меня этих файлов может быть 20+ шт. мне нужно прописать 20 подключений к HTML? Мне кажется, должен быть более изящный способ.

Comment: Динамически добавьте 20 елементов script в документ.

Comment: И этот способ есть! Использовать сборщик, например `gulp`, для соединения всех файлов в один файл.

Comment: "Каким образом я могу соединить файлы" - а их соидениять явно не нужно. Если подключить 20 раз script - то любая ф-ция любого из этих скриптов сможет обратится к именованым елементам любого из 20-ти скриптов.

Comment: webpack нужно использовать. Он и постоит правильное дерево зависимостей.

Comment: Подождите грузить утилитами, может просто в даном случае достаточно сказать 1.файл html `<script src=file1.js /><script src=file2.js />`  a в самом файле можно делать "именованые" ссылки на другой.

Comment: Опубликуйте ваши файлы взяв их в `{}` в редакторе. Или хотя бы пользуйтесь обратными апострофами ` двумя. Покажите что у вас не получается.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/World.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Vector.js">  </script>

class Vector {
  constructor(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

//в соседнем файле:

var x = new Vector(1,5);


//Uncaught ReferenceError: turn is not defined
    at World.js:30`

Comment: А вы поменяйте строчки в html World.js и Vector.js местами, поскольку имя Vector будет доступно после подключения а не до.

Comment: Cпасибо! совсем забыл про последовательное выполнение скриптов. Закончу задачу так, потом прочитаю про вебпак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вопроса можно последовательно (!!!) подключить необходимое количество скриптов к html документу, после этого будет возможность создавать именованные объекты одного класса в другом.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/World.js"> </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Vector.js"> </script>
```